# Query/Filter based off dynamic content sent in 1 send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, query, filters, dynamic

I have a welcome email, which dynamically (through AMPScript) shows one content to users who have already subscribed, and a different content to new users.

Now I want to add a drip two of my campaign, but ONLY to the new users. Is there a way to query or build a filter/measure of only people send one version of this email? The content for each version is saved in the portfolio.

Comment: Hi dtay, can you provide more information about how the Welcome Email is being sent? The more detail you can provide, the better the answers we can give you :)

Comment: Thanks Cameron, it's a triggered email, from an API call. It sends as soon as we receive the info. The subscriber is added to all subscribers as well as a data extension specific for this welcome. Let me know if there's anything else that could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the extra info Dtay.

You could try using [**LookupRows**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuprows/) (or just [**Lookup**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookup/)) to search for the subscriber in the [**_Subscribers**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/) data view.

My interpretation is that Subscribers are added "on send", so if they are new, they wont exist at the time this AMPScript runs. This means you can use [**RowCount**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/rowcount/) to count the LookupRows; if 0, then they don't exist, and are therefore "new".

However, if Salesforce does add the Subscriber *before* the AMPScript runs, then you may want to check the "DateJoined" field against the [**Now()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/now/) DateTime using [**DateDiff**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/datediff/). If the Subscriber joined < 1 Day ago, then they are "new"; anything larger than that would be "existing".

Depending on your PrimaryKey in Salesforce (SubscriberKey or EmailAddress), you may need to use [**LookupOrderedRows**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuporderedrows/) to make sure you select the "newest" record (Ordinal #3 = "DateJoined DESC").